# Add text to raphaelJS pie chart?

Tags: javascript, css, raphael

Trying to create an interactive pie chart and raphaelJS seemed like the best solution.  I have almost zero experience with it, (though I'm fairly proficient with jquery) so pardon if I come off as a complete idiot.

Question:  I've created a functional interactive pie chart that displays text on hover.  My problem is that I can't figure out how to style the text as I need to - adding  and

tags to the html doesn't have an effect

Here is the script - I'll try to just include the relevant sections:

```
var angle = -18,
    total = 0,
    start = 0,
    process = function (j) {
        var value = values[j],
            angleplus = 360 * value / total,
            popangle = angle + (angleplus / 2), // angle of text display
            color = Raphael.hsb(start, .9, 1),
            ms = 300,
            delta = 30,
            bcolor = Raphael.hsb(start, 1, 1),
            p = sector(cx, cy, r, angle, angle + angleplus, {
                fill: "90-" + bcolor + "-" + color,
                stroke: "#F3F5F2",
                "stroke-width": 4,
                "stroke-opacity": 1,
                opacity: .5}),
            txt = paper.text(cx + (r + delta + 155) * Math.cos(0 * rad),
                cy + (r + delta + 75) * Math.sin(-10 * rad),
                labels[j]).attr({
                    fill: "#111",
                    stroke: "none",
                    opacity: 0,
                    "font-family": "Gotham",
                    "font-size": 14});
    });
```

Here's the jsfiddle with the rest of the script and html (can't get it to run correctly though, works fine normally)  - http://jsfiddle.net/9L286/

Currently, "txt" defines the style for text - I want to be able to style both the title ("item 1") and the description.  Hopefully I'm just blind and there's a simple solution.  If more info is needed, just ask.  Thanks!

Comment: I'd probably try and get a test example on a jsfiddle.

Comment: added a jsfiddle - but for some reason the script won't load correctly...  Works fine normally